# Math/equation keys in pgfkeys and tikz picture

Tags: pgfkeys

I am using `pgfkeys` as variables of a newcommand for TikZ pictures. I can transfer numerical values and simple math correctly. However, some math expressions are not transferred to the command. A MWE is provided below.

Why an equality expression and the `\unitfrac` are not working?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/mycom/.is family, /mycom,
default/.style={text = $?$},
text/.estore in = \mytext}

\newcommand{\mycom}[1][]{
\pgfkeys{/mycom, default, #1}
%some tikx command to display the math
\draw (0,0) node{\mytext};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%\mycom[text = aa]                         % Does work
%\mycom[text = $5x$]                       % Does work
%\mycom[text = $5x+6$]                     % Does work
%\mycom[text = $5x=6$]                     % Does not work
%\mycom[text = $\unitfrac[10]{kN}{m}$]     % Does not work
%\mycom[text = $\si{\kilo\newton/\meter}$] % Does work

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: In general I'd use `\per` instead of `/` in `\si`, and say `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}` to get a `/` in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `=` needs to be protected to stop PGF trying to parse it. For the second case, you need not to expand it so soon. If you use `.store` rather than `.estore`, this all works just fine.

The counter is only for testing because the uncommented code typeset all nodes in the same place.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/mycom/.is family, /mycom,
  default/.style={text = $?$},
  text/.store in = \mytext}
\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand{\mycom}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/mycom, default, #1}%
  %some tikx command to display the math
  \draw (\thefoo,0) node {\mytext};%
  \stepcounter{foo}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mycom[text = aa]                         % Does work
  \mycom[text = $5x$]                       % Does work
  \mycom[text = $5x+6$]                     % Does work
  \mycom[text = {$5x=6$}]                     % Does not work
  \mycom[text = {$\unitfrac[10]{kN}{m}$}]     % Does not work
  \mycom[text = $\si{\kilo\newton/\meter}$] % Does work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you changhe your icon?:-) +1 for your answer.

Comment: @cfr: I have been using .estore for a reason that I do not remember now. There are some discussion about the use of .estore [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324973/96172). Do you have any comments?

Comment: @cfr: Regarding `$a=b$`. How come the $-signs are ignored? I thought the math enviroment provides the necessary protection. Thoughts?

Comment: @cfr: Seems like we need to add the `{ }` to the `$\unitfrac[]{}{}$` along with the `.store`. Why do we need the brackets here?

Comment: @cfr: The MWE is actually a package I am working on. To make the code more suitable for end-user, is there any other option without the curly brackets?

Comment: @BarisErkus PGF basically uses its own parser. You have to be very careful about when things are expanded.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes ;).

Comment: @BarisErkus Well, sometimes you want full expansion and sometimes you don't. As egreg says there, many macros won't survive the use of `.estore in`. There is no general rule here saying one is better or worse than the other. It depends what you need.