# Conflict in the Key Values in Nested Tikz Enviroments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikzmath

I am developing some Tikz commands with pgfkeys, and I want to use the commands that I developed earlier in my new commands. This creates nested Tikz and Tikz math enviroments as shown in the MWE given below.

Without changing the variable names, how can I pass the correct value of `\a` in the second call to the `\testing`, which is 3, not 4? I think in the MWE, the name `\b` is passed to the command, not 3.

The reason I am asking this question is I do not want to know the key variables used in the command `\testing` for a better coding.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfkeys{
 /testing/.is family,
 /testing,
  b/.store in =\b,  
  a/.store in =\a}

\newcommand{\testing}[1][]{\pgfkeys{/testing, #1}
\tikzmath{
real \a, \b;
print ($Out:$);
print ($a = \a,$);
print ($b = \b |$);
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\b = 3;}
\path(0,-0.5) -- (6,0.5);
\testing[a = 1, b = 2]     %Result: a = 1, b = 2
\testing[a = \b, b = 4]    %Result: a = 4, b = 4. Should be: a = 3, b = 4.
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't nest `tikzpicture` environments. It is unsupported. In very simple cases, it may happen to work. But, if it does, that's just luck and it is liable to break at any time.

Comment: I am trying to develop a package with many custom commands in it. Each command uses the structure shown above. The problem occured when I was developing a new command and had to call another command I had already written. Seems like I have to make all keys private to avoid the conflict, or this is not a common way of developing packages?

Comment: to be honest, it is very unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish, from the MWE. Can you give an explanation of why you are expecting 3,4?

Comment: It is not common practice to use the same name for multiple things in a package, no. Also, it would be better to use package specific names and avoid single letter macros. For the immediate problem, you can try `.estore in`, but I really wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: I was going to suggest `.estore in` too but I agree with @cfr that this looks wrong. Also, consider that these are local definitions, so if you wrap groups around them you may be able to control their scope better.

Comment: One can generally avoid nesting tikz by using saveboxes.

Comment: @cfr: There are some discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324973/96172) regarding the use of .estore. However, in one of my earlier [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373478/96172), I had some side effects of .estore. I will make an edit and try to clarify my intention.

Comment: You can't use the same macro for two distinct values at the same time. If you say `\b=3` and then say `\b=4`, then `\b=4`. It is that simple. You must use a different name or ensure that the name is never set at the wrong time. I don't understand why you expect there to be a way to have `\b` produce `3` when you've set `\b` to `4`. If you want it to be `3`, don't set it to `4`!

Answer (score 2):

TeX is not a programming language, neither is PGFKeys nor TikZMath.
Macros aren't variables.

If you use `a = \b`, the macro `\b` will be stored in `\a` not its value (i.e. its expansion).

If you want to store `\b`'s expansion in `\a` you will either have to define the key

```
a/.estore in=\a
```

(which will always fully expand the value of the key)

or use it with

```
a/.expand once=\b
```

so that it expands `\b` only once.

Comment: I agree with most of your premises, but if “TeX is not a programming language”, what is it?  Some Turing-complete markup language?  

Don’t get me wrong, please … Having lived about 30 years with the notion of TeX (the primitives) being a programming language, and having seen moon rover software written in TeX, and knowing a guy that made a living by configuring ethernet routers on cruise ships with LaTeX (sic, and typesetting the connection diagrams describing that with TikZs) encourages me in that, to be honest.